# Haystack Search in Django only allow template to work

Tags: django, django-haystack

I'm working with Haystack. Below is my Model and Index.

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Record(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name="Hostname")
   address = models.CharField(max_length=50)

   def __str__(self):
      return self.name
```

Also my index is as follows:

```
class RecordIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
   text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True, use_template=True)
   name = indexes.CharField(model_attr="name")

   def get_model(self):
      return Record

   def index_queryset(self, using=None):
      return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

Then my template file is

```
{{ object.name }}
{{ object.address }}
```

Then I tried using SearchQueryAPI like this.

```
 SearchQuerySet().filter(name=record.name).models(Record)
```

But this didn't work.Next, I tried this.

```
SearchQuerySet().filter(text=record.name).models(Record)
```

This worked. Can anyone tell me why? Also, want to know if I can not only use template to make this work?

Comment: What does "didn't work" entail? errors? invalid results?

Comment: Did you update your index ?

Comment: @BabacarGningue I just tried to update my index and it worked! why did the template method still worked when I didn't update the index? I did use RealTimeSignalProcessor for real-time update...

Comment: @Sayse it didn't work refers to not filtering any results.